Base change of a hensel DVR
Let $k$ be a perfect field of character $p$. Consider a hensel discrete valuation ring $R$ of characteristic $p$ with uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field $k=R/\pi$.
Let $k'/k$ be a finite extension. Is $R\otimes_k k'$ necessarily a hensel DVR?

I'm reading Laumon's paper Transformation de Fourier, constantes d’équations
fonctionnelles et conjecture de Weil. For hensel traits $T,T'$ with residue fields equal to $k$, Laumon defined the local Fourier transform $Sh(\eta)->Sh(\eta')$ for sheaves on the generic points.
In 2.5.2, Laumon claimed that we may assume $k$ is algebraically closed by passing to a field extension. To do this, we need to know that the base change $T\times_k k'$ is still a hensel DVR. But I can't even tell if $T\times_k k'$ is a local ring.

A finite extension of a henselian local ring is not necessarily local, but it is always a product of henselian local rings.
